# C# - Calling a variable stored in a form by passing that form in a class

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title explains, I want to access two variables, that have the same type and name, stored in two different Windows Form (Form1 and Form2) in a third Class (Class3). 
The variable is called test, and it is defined in each Form as:

```
public static int test;
```

Class3 is defined as:

```
private Form parentForm;
//constructor 
public Class3(Form f)
{
   parentForm = f;
}

public void Main()
{
   parentForm.test = 3;
}
```

Then, in each Form I create the object of Class3 and I call its Main method:

```
Class3 c3 = new Class3(this);
c3.Main();
```

In this way I should be able to set test equal to three in both Form1 and Form2, but I got an error when typing parentForm.test = 3, saying that "'Form' does not contain a definition for 'test' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?".

Instead, if I try to access 'test' using directly the name of the Form without using the parentForm, I do not have the error:

```
Form1.test = 3;
```

I think that I am missing something when passing the Form reference to Class3. Can you tell me where is the mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you define a static variable, it belongs to the type (e.g. `Form1`) instead to a specific object (e.g. `parentForm`). See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

So you need to change the declaration to:

```
public int test;
```

With that said, public fields are not considered good practice, so it would be better to use a property, like this:

```
public int Test { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing what I think you're doing, you probably have something that looks like this:

**Form1.cs**

```
public class Form1: Form {
  public static int test;
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
public class Form2: Form {
  public static int test;
}
```

If that's the case, then how you're approaching it needs a few tweaks. Instead of extending `Form` outright you need to first create a new base class that extends the `Form` first, that way each class has access to the static variable `test`. Otherwise, both classes will contain their own `test` value. So, create a class `BaseForm` like this:

```
public class BaseForm: Form {
  public static int test;
}
```

This allows us to extend that with both forms, giving each class access to the static value.

```
public class Form1: BaseForm {
}

public class Form2: BaseForm {
}
```

Then, in your `Class3` you would have it look like this:

```
private BaseForm parentForm;
//constructor 
public Class3(BaseForm f)
{
   parentForm = f;
}

public void Main()
{
   BaseForm.test = 3;
}
```

Now, notice how I didn't access the `test` value with the `parentForm` object, this is because the value is `static` and not `instance` accessible. Meaning, an `instance` (i.e `parentForm`) is not able to access a variable within the `static` scope, so, we assign the value using the `BaseForm` class.

Comment: Thanks @QuietOran, now everything is working. I have another question for you: do you know if there is any way to access the `test` value with the `parentForm` object using a specific type of test (not `static`)? Do I have to create this sort of a "bridge class" (`BaseForm`) necessarily? In my application, `test` does not have to necessarily assume the same value in the two classes (it can be a local variable for both `Form1` and `Form2`).

Comment: If that's the case you can remove the `static` keyword from the `test` object. That will give you an instance based value that can be assigned per instance. And having the `BaseForm` parent class would be necessary in this case. Then you can change the value via `parentForm.test = 3`.